# Get Test Sets in an Iteration with REST api

Tags: rally

I am working with the Rally REST API's, version 3 beta.

How do you to get the list of Test Sets in a particular Iteration?

For other entities I'm working on, I am finding it easy to navigate the tree as there is a URL to the collection as part of the parent. Test Sets appear under an Iteration in the UI but do not seem to fit anywhere in the object graph in the web services.

This is as far as I got:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v3.0/testset
   ?workspace=<workspace ref>
   &project=<project ref>
   &query=(Iteration.Name="Sprint 82")
```

But it gives an error: Could not parse: Unknown operator ")"

If I remove the parenthesis, it can't parse the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting spaces around the = operator:

```
query=(Iteration.Name = "Sprint 82")
```